# akeeba backup error with database connection

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have taken akeeba backup from my site and unzipped it. WHen I try to go to the index.php page, instead of the akeeba backup installation screen, I get the following error message

```
Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL
```

I tried editing the configuration.php file with the database info, but it does not help. Also, since I am trying to restore from backup, I have simply created a blank database and am trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly?  Restore a site that was backed up using Akeeba?

If so you can't unzip it - you'll need to download kickstart.php.  Put that in the root where you want the backup to appear along with the backup.  Then go to http://yoursite.com/futurejoomlaroot/kickstart.php and that should get you through the installation process.

Kickstart.php should be found here:  https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/official/akeeba-kickstart.html

Note - if you were going from a local host to a remote host you may need to also add a database user on your remote site (along with that blank database, and give that user access to that database).  Also check the permissions on the folder you're installing it to.

If I'm offbase give us a bit more information (step by step would be useful).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Joomla, or which version of Akeeba, but what is above is pretty accurate.
However, you don't need kickstart.

If you're restoring from a backup - simply place it in your joomla folder and navigate to that folder/domain.

For example in a hosted scenario, if you've unzipped all your files in the root directory of your domain, go to "www .yourdomain.com" - no need to put index.php on the end of it.  Then the installation process will start without issue.  You're seeing that because you're trying to access a page directly and the SQL Database connection hasn't been established yet.

If you're working on a local copy it would just be navigating to the directory where it is installed.

Don't include index.php and you should be fine.